# Debugging broken Sublime Text 3 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

After installing a couple of Sublime Text packages, some of the previous keyboard shortcuts were broken.

What's the best way to find the package which defines a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the next person some time trying to debug this situation:

To enable logging in your Sublime Text window, first open the Python console by typing:

```
    CTRL-`
```

Then run this command to enable logging of commands:

```
    sublime.log_commands(True)
```

With the output you see in the console, it should be easier to identify the offending package which overrides a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer the Plugin `Keymaps`.

Quote from the [readme](https://github.com/MiroHibler/sublime-keymaps):

> Plugin for Sublime Text 2/3 editor that enables searching for keymaps by function as well as showing all enabled keymaps in a searchable color-coded list - Cheat Sheet.

So can simply install it with [`package control`](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and search for entries.